# Consume the results of Neo4j driver in java

Tags: java, neo4j

Using Neo4j driver for java, i want to send a search query to the database such as:

```
MATCH(a:`Label`{Property:"NODE_PROPERTY"})
RETURN *
```

First i create a session and the i use the run methods of the driver to run a query:

```
Result run = session.run(query);
```

run variable contains a list of Records. My question is how can i consume the records so that i can convert them to java objects? I tried to get the values of the results but since they're not iterable, it's not possible to get them one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Result` implements `Iterator<Record>`, so there is a bunch of ways of consuming it, e.g.:

**While loop** (Java 6 style):

```java
Result result = session.run(query);
List<MyPojo> myList = new ArrayList<>();
while(result.hasNext()) {
    Record r = result.next();
    myList.add(mapToMyPojo(r));
}
```

**Stream** (Java 8+ style):

```java
Result result = session.run(query);
List<MyPojo> myList = result.stream()
    .map(record -> mapToMyPojo(record))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Using** [Result.list(Function<Record,T> mapFunction)](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/java-driver/current/org/neo4j/driver/Result.html#list-java.util.function.Function-):

```
Result result = session.run(query);
List<MyPojo> myList = result.list(r -> mapToMyPojo(r));
```

Mapping to a Java object is pretty stright-forward:

```java
public MyPojo mapToMyPojo(Record record) {
    MyPojo pojo = new MyPojo();
    pojo.setProperty(record.get("Property").asString());
    // ...
    return pojo;
}
```

Although instead of mapping results manually, you might want to use [neo4j-ogm](https://neo4j.com/developer/neo4j-ogm/)